# Redmine Email Configuration - An error occurred while sending mail (530 5.7.0 Authentication required )

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, redmine

My configuration.yml looks like this

```
default:
 configuration
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:

      address: "mail.example.com"
      port: 25
      domain: "example.com"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "redmine@example.com"
      password: "xxxxxxxx"
```

I am getting the message An error occurred while sending mail (530 5.7.0 Authentication required ) while treying to send a test mail.

I have tried out different options with starttls, removing.adding quotes. It does not work. The configuration details work fine with Thunderbird. Somehow it does not work here.

Please note my redmine setup is on AWS and my mail server is on another shared hosting. Does it has anything to do with the security groups?

Please guide me fix the issue. Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change default to production or development, and configuration line is too much so your config would look like this:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "mail.example.com"
      port: 25
      domain: "example.com"
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "redmine@example.com"
      password: "xxxxxxxx"
```